# Magento 2 - Open cart products by default, in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3.4

The products are hidden by default in the checkout

[image]

How can I show them by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to overwrite the template **vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary\cart-items.html** in your own theme and replace:

```
<div class="block items-in-cart" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active', 'active': isItemsBlockExpanded()}}">
```

with:

```
<div class="block items-in-cart" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active', 'active': true}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps:

**FROM:**

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/sum‌mary/cart-items.js
```

**TO:**

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme-name}/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/summary/cart-items.js
```

Replace below code in that file.

```
isItemsBlockExpanded: function () { 
   /*return quote.isVirtual() || stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping'); */       
    return true;
 }
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, you can accept the answer so it can help others also.